# Можно ли как-то преобразовать из строки в цифру

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

У меня geojson файл, где есть поля с числами(идет как string), например "500", можно ли как-то сделать чтобы он стал типом number и выводился 500.00
Пробовал toFixed(2), но понимаю, что метод преобразует число в строку и при преобразовании в число выводится просто 500

Answer (score 0):

> можно ли как-то сделать чтобы он стал типом number

Можно. Нужно запарсить число. Либо `parseInt`, либо `parseFloat` (если дробная часть имеет значение):

```
const num = parseFloat("500"); // 500
```

> и выводился 500.00

Вот тут уже не совсем можно. Дело в том, что перед выводом число будет преобразовано обратно в строку. Преобразовано оно будет неявно, если вы делаете просто `console.log(num)` или `document.write(num)`. Но вы можете преобразовать его явно. Для указания длины дробной части можно воспользоваться методом `toFixed`:

```
const str = num.toFixed(2); // 2 - количество знаков после запятой. Вывод: "500.00"
```

Comment: В этом и проблема что выводится как стринг, а мне нужен number

Comment: Любые данные выводятся как строки. Что вы подразумеваете под словом "выводится"?

Comment: При формировании geojson был number, а не строка

Comment: Так чем `parseFloat` не подходит?

Comment: Просто преобразует в число, но не добавляет .00 в этом и была проблема